# how to get python 2.7 into the system path on Redhat 6.5 Linux

Tags: python, linux, ipython, redhat

I have installed (or so I think) python 2.7.5. When I type **"Python --version" I get python2.7.5**

I've narrowed this down to:

1. When I run "python" in a terminal in my /Home/UsrName/ directory it is version 2.7.5
2. However when I run "python" in a terminal in /Home/UserName/Downloads/Ipython directory I get 2.6.6

I went into the Ipython folder to run the Ipython Setup file. I think I need to add python27 to a system path so that when I am inside the /Home/UserName/Downloads/Ipython directory and run the install file Ipython knows I am using a required version of python.

I am not sure how to add python27 to the system on redhat linux 6.5 (Also I am not even sure that this will fix it).

Comment: `Python` and `python` are not the same thing. The first one shouldn't even exist on linux. Also, it sounds like `.` may be on your `PATH`, which is generally considered a bad idea on linux. Also, I don't know what you mean by "the install file ipython", but the best way to install things that don't have RPMs is with the `pip` command, not by downloading and running installers (or by running them directly out of source).

Comment: sorry abarnert - to clarify what I mean is: whe I am inside the ipython directory and I open a terminal and type "python" it is only aware of python 2.6.6. But when I am in my /Home/Josh/ Directory python is 2.7.5. How do I get my terminal open inside the Ipython directory to recognise there is a python 2.7.5?

Comment: If which version gets found by the `python` command depends on your current working directory, that probably means you have `.` in your `PATH` (or some other non-absolute path), which is something you probably want to fix. You can `echo $PATH` to see for sure.

Comment: abarnert - echo $PATH returns: "[joserry@oc6133468658 bin]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ibm/c4eb/bin:/home/joserry/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin
"

Comment: How does one remove say python 2.7 in the event I want to try installing all over again (On redhat linux 6.5) using YUM.

Comment: You still haven't told us how you installed Python 2.7, so we can't tell you how to uninstall it. If you installed it with `yum` or `rpm`, you can uninstall it with `yum` or `rpm`. (And if you don't know how to do that, you should be asking on SuperUser or a RHEL/Fedora-specific site, not StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 4):

Redhat depends on a specific version of Python for `yum` to function properly. Because of this the recommended way of python installing is an alt-install.

A very good tutorial can be found [here](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/):

A short summary of commands to run (from the previous link):

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

now install pip:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
python2.7 ez_setup.py
easy_install-2.7 pip
```

If you need compiled extensions to be installed (such as scipy), you might need to follow operations described [here](http://www.shocksolution.com/2011/08/how-to-build-scippy-with-python-2-7-2-on-centos5/) (scipy-specific, but gives you ideas about how to proceed)

Comment: The `ez_setup.py` instructions are out of date. The right way to install `pip` nowadays is the `get-pip` script. See [Installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#installation) in the docs.

Comment: Unless you've installed a `python27` RPM, in which case there should be a `python27-pip` RPM to go with it…

Comment: @abarnert: does it properly manage the conflict between pip and pip2.7?

Comment: `get-pip` should. I don't know about any `python27-pip` RPM, but since the two people who wrote [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) are/were RedHat employees, I'd guess yes. He can always list the files before installing (but I don't remember the command to do that).

Comment: Actually, if the two of them had gotten their way, a Python 2.7.8 source build would have included the same `pip` bootstrap that 3.4+ have, which would have solved this problem permanently… but sadly, that isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have your $PATH fine, as you can run python without specifying full path, aka /usr/bin/python.

You get 2.6.6 in Ipython directory because it has python executable in it, named, wild guess - python.  2.7.5 is installed system-wide. To call 2.7.5 from the Ipython dir, use full path /usr/bin/python, or whatever `which python` points to.

Try out python virtualenv if you need two or more version of python on your system. Otherwise, having different versions is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

Open up your terminal's config file (e.g. .bashrc, .zshrc, .profile -- I'm not sure about Redhat, so whichever one you normally use) and remove the path to the default version of Python and replace it with your 2.7.5 version, like this:

```
# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=YOUROTHERPATHLOCATIONS:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7.5/bin
```

Or you keep both versions and alias 2.7.5 like this:

```
alias python275="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7.5/bin/python"
```

You might consider using virtualenv for your projects instead, though.

Comment: He should already have symlinks or wrapper executables named `python2.7` and `python2.6`, so the alias shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening - abarnert pointed out that the cwd (".") may be in your path which is why you get the local python when you're running in that directory. Because the cwd is not normally setup in the global bashrc file (/etc/bashrc) it's probably in your local ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile. So edit those files and look for something like PATH=$PATH:. and remove that line. Then open a new window (or logout and log back in) to refresh the path setting and you should be OK.

Comment: Actually, just re-`source`-ing the scripts won't help if your current path is already screwed up. You can manually fix it temporarily, or you can just (depending on which file it was in) close your shell and open a new one, close your shell and open a new login shell, or logout and login completely.